# Replacing [word] [space] [word] strings with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Substituting one/two-word suburbs. Matching dictionary keys with dictionary values for lines of addresses. For example:

```
32 Konini Street Eastbourne Retired
6 Moana Road Days Bay Retailer
```

Expected output:

```
32 Konini Street _Eastbourne Retired
6 Moana Road _Days_Bay Retailer
```

Code:

```
# Parsing words of line for single/double word dictionary key 
# replacing found instances with underscore version
lines = ['6 Moana Road Days Bay Retailer','32 Konini Street Eastbourne Retired'] 
sampleDictionary = {"Days Bay":"_Days_Bay","Eastbourne":"_Eastbourne"}
newString = ''
doubleWordLists = []



for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i] 
    splits = line.split(' ')

    # Unused block
    for j in range(len(splits)):
        if j + 1 < len(splits):
            doubleWord = splits[j] + ' ' + splits[j + 1]
            doubleWordLists.append(doubleWord)
        
    # Compare a token with dictionary. If no match compare that token and next. 
    # Add appropriate token(s) to new string 
    for j in range(len(splits)):

        if splits[j] != '\d':
            for key in sampleDictionary:
                value = sampleDictionary[key]
                
            if key == splits[j]:
                newString += value + ' '
            else:
                #if key == doubleWordLists[j]:
                #   newString += value + ' '              
                newString += splits[j] + ' '
        else:
            newString += splits[j] + ' '

print(newString)
```

Output:

```
6 Moana Road Days Bay Retailer 32 Konini Street _Eastbourne Retired
```

As the code shows I have tried to access `doubleWordLists` as a way to match and replace the two word suburb in the string. See commented out lines. But I was not able to do it while keeping within index of `splits[j]`

The issues are: supplying a two word match to a dictionary and having the means to substitute the returned dictionary `value` back into the string at the correct index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my readable solution, hope it helps you:

```
# Parsing words of line for single/double word dictionary key 
# replacing found instances with underscore version
lines = ['6 Moana Road Days Bay Retailer', '32 Konini Street Eastbourne Retired']
sampleDictionary = {"Days Bay": "_Days_Bay", "Eastbourne": "_Eastbourne"}

def replaceLine(line, sampleDictionary):
    replaced_line = line
    for sample, replacement in sampleDictionary.items():
        if sample in line:
            replaced_line = line.replace(sample, replacement)
    return replaced_line


replacedLines = [replaceLine(line, sampleDictionary) for line in lines]

print(" ".join(replacedLines))
# 6 Moana Road _Days_Bay Retailer 32 Konini Street _Eastbourne Retired
```